# Which Api Gateway Platform should you recommend for a simple Microservice Apps?

Tags: spring-boot, cloud, microservices, api-gateway, kong

I've recently started learning about microservices and what surrounds them, such as API gateways
and at this moment I am trying to choose the best tool/tools for API Gateway Platform or Pattern. 
I know you need to get my requirements to enable to recommend it. 
While thinking simple, 
Reverse Proxy, Http Header/Body Adjusting, Http Load Balancing and Authorization/Authentication are our requirements at the first step and It is important that I am able to make dockerized that API platform.

Note that: My microservice apps are based on Spring boot app.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In the spring ecosystem, the choice mainly consists of:

- [Spring Cloud Gateway](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-gateway)
- [Zuul](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html)

In your case, I would recommend [Spring Cloud Gateway](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/). 
Its main advantage is that it is not blocked, unlike Zuul.